# Showing Visual Studio 2008 Code Coverage and Code Metrics in CruiseControl.NET Build Report

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am setting up a fresh Continuous Integration environment for a .NET project. The basics are in place and I have also integrated the Visual Studio Code Analysis (FxCopCmd.exe) and Test Results (MSTest.exe).

How to do that?
a. Add an  task for above mentioned tools, specify input dll and output xml/trx in the .build file of the project
b. Update ccnet.config, add  blocks for those xml/trx files
c. Update dashboard.config, add  block with fxcop-summary_1_36.xsl and MsTestSummary2008.xsl

Everything looks and works great. Now I also want to show Visual Studio 2008 Code Coverage and Code Metrics in CruiseControl.NET 1.5.7385.9 Build Report. Can somebody tell me how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

These links provides some clues:
- blogs.msdn.com/b/ms_joc/archive/2005/04/08/406608.aspx
- groups.google.com.ag/group/ccnet-user/browse_thread/thread/63c5b36a24f4366a

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the tool [NDepend](http://www.NDepend.com) integrated inside [your continuous integration process](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Details.aspx) to [gather NCover, dotCover or Visual Studio coverage metrics](http://www.ndepend.com/Coverage.aspx). *Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the tool*

Then you can write [Code Rules over LINQ Queries](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) concerning coverage data. Some Code Rules are proposed by default, this includes for example:

- [Types that used to be 100% covered but not anymore](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Types_that_used_to_be_100__covered_but_not_anymore.html)
- [From now, all types added or refactored should be 100% covered by tests](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_From_now,_all_types_added_or_refactored_should_be_100__covered_by_tests.html)
- [Complex methods partially covered by tests should be 100% covered](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Complex_methods_partially_covered_by_tests_should_be_100__covered.html)
- [C.R.A.P method code metric](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_C.R.A.P_method_code_metric.html)